# Android Studio - can't download google apis intel x86 atom system image

Tags: android, java-7, android-studio-2.2, jdk1.7

I've installed Android Studio - Version 2.2 and jdk version 1.7.0_72. During the installation an error occurred "Warning: An error occurred while preparing sdk package google apis intel x86 atom system image". I've posted the image here, [during_installation_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txf6h.png). Though there was an error showing I skipped that and clicked finish. But when I ran Android Studio it was showing "Your Android SDK is missing, out of date, or is missing templates." The image is here...[after_installation_problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A4iA.png). I'm stucked on that..please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the entire `sdk` folder and re-ran Android Studio to let it redownload everything.